# Provider ID must be specified for oauth2 client?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

I am trying setting up a oauth2 client with spring-boot. I have this dependencies on my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this configuration on my `application.properties`:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-id=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.client-secret=...
```

and this security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

whe I try run the application, give me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider ID must be specified for client registration 'mercadolivre'
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getBuilder(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:95) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistration(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.lambda$getClientRegistrations$0(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1338) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.clientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 110 common frames omitted
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're missing the OAuth2 provider you'll be authorizing with, as described in the [Spring reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#oauth2login-custom-provider-properties).

Thesse are some of the properties you should provide:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.mercadolivre.provider=mercadolivre

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.authorization-uri=...
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.mercadolivre.token-uri=...
```

Comment: The link to the Spring reference is dead (since "current" is a moving target). Here ist a working link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#oauth2login-custom-provider-properties

Answer (score 5):

With YML:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: clientId
            clientSecret: clientSecret
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: clientName
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{poolId}
            user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

Source: [Authenticating with Amazon Cognito Using Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito)